# How to 'update table, if table exists' with MySQL Dump?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently dumping MySQL tables with `mysqldump`.

The dump is currently producing:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `versions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `versions` (
  `major` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `minor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `revision` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `build` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_installed` datetime NOT NULL,
  `current` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_class_name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lazy_load` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sitewide` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `versions_pkey` (`product`,`major`,`minor`,`revision`,`build`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I'd like the dump to say is something like,

```
IF TABLE EXISTS, UPDATE IT TO MATCH THIS STRUCTURE (
  `major` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `minor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `revision` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `build` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_installed` datetime NOT NULL,
  `current` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_class_name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lazy_load` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sitewide` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `versions_pkey` (`product`,`major`,`minor`,`revision`,`build`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is this possible through MySQL dump (or indeed any other MySQL-related tools)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to dump the schema ahead of time and convert `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-data --skip-add-drop-table ... --all-databases | sed 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' > MYSQLSchema.sql
```

This will bypass adding the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS versions;` command and transform `CREATE TABLE` into `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: To export a specific DB, I have used `mysqldump -u myusername -pmypassword --skip-add-drop-table --no-data --single-transaction database_name | sed 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' > db.sql`

Answer (score 0):

When you dump the database, you can set/reset the flag that generates the DROP TABLE command.